# distinct list LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to return a distinct list of SubString in LINQ.

This is returning the list but there are 100 records with the substring. I only want to return the distinct list.

```
var query = from b in db.Certificates
            select b.CertificateNumber.Substring(0,4);

ViewBag.BoxNumber = new SelectList(query.ToList());
```

I tried adding the distinct as in

```
select b.CertificateNumber.Substring(0,4).Distinct();
```

But it threw

> > DbDistinctExpression requires a collection argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you're currently doing it, it's going to attempt to do a Distinct on the first four characters of each certificate number (stripping out duplicate characters), then return *all* of the results. You're probably getting the error because the driver you're using is unable to create a valid SQL query that way.

Instead, surround the entire first part of the query in parentheses before calling `Distinct`, like this:

```
var query = (from b in db.Certificates
             select b.CertificateNumber.Substring(0,4)).Distinct();
```

Alternatively, using method syntax instead of a mixture of query and method syntax:

```
var query = db.Certificates
              .Select(cer => cer.CertificateNumber.Substring(0,4))
              .Distinct();
```

Comment: How would I order by the resulting list?

Comment: Thank You! Gonna ask a new question on updating using that value, don't want to do it here, might get yelled at.

Comment: How would I add a where clause to this where Active='Y'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68851/discussion-between-doug-farrell-and-grant-winney).

Answer (score 1):

I got it

```
ViewBag.BoxNumber = new SelectList(query.ToList().Distinct());
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401772/iqueryable-distinct-vs-listt-distinct look at this comparison and take my advice running distinct, then tolist

Comment: I don't think you got it. If you had got it, you would've chosen Grant's answer as the right answer. Because, his answer does the same thing in a nicer way.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var certificatesList = (from b in db.Certificates
                    select b.CertificateNumber.Substring(0,4)).Distinct().ToList();
```