# Distinct not working in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

function for get list of documents name only with distinct...

```
public static List<DocumentTypeModel> GetUploadedDocumentsName(int TicketId)
{
    List<DocumentTypeModel> documents = new List<DocumentTypeModel>();
    using (var db = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        documents = db.tbl_TrnTicketDocument.Get(x => x.FK_TicketId == TicketId && x.IsActive == true).Select(s => new DocumentTypeModel()
        {
            DocumentTypeNameEnglish = s.tbl_MstDocumentType.DocumentTypeNameEnglish
        }).Distinct().ToList();
    }
    return documents;
}
```

currently result is this -

> Affidavit in Case of Cancelled Will/No Will
>
> Affidavit in Case of Cancelled Will/No Will
>
> Allotment Letter
>
> Allotment Letter
>
> Death Certificate
>
> Death Certificate
>
> Lease Deed
>
> Lease Deed
>
> Photo Identity of Applicant
>
> Photo Identity of Applicant
>
> Possession Letter
>
> Possession Letter
>
> Registered/Unregistered Will
>
> Registered/Unregistered Will

Comment: probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401772/iqueryable-distinct-vs-listt-distinct should help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use groupby and select first option like this:

```
List<DocumentTypeModel> documents = new List<DocumentTypeModel>();
using (var db = new UnitOfWork())
{
   documents = db.tbl_TrnTicketDocument.Get(x => x.FK_TicketId == TicketId && x.IsActive == true).Select(s => new DocumentTypeModel()
   {
   DocumentTypeNameEnglish = s.tbl_MstDocumentType.DocumentTypeNameEnglish
   }).ToList();

   documents = documents.GroupBy(x => x.DocumentTypeNameEnglish).Select(g => g.First());
}
```

Comment: 2 questions, doesn't this return all results in first enumeration of the data? and shouldn't you call .GroupBy before the first select to reduce the number of enumerations to 1?

Comment: Thing is - there is no such think as DistictByField in SQL, so grouping by is probably best bet. Agree with you Neel. Voted up - answer is defenetly right.

Answer (score 1):

Distinct() doesn't work like you tried on objects. Use IComparer to get this working https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320727

Create a comparer class

```
public class DocumentTypeModelComparer: IComparer
{
  int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
 {
   if(a.Id == b.ID)
     return 0;
   else
     return 1;
  }
}
```

Now in your lambda expression

```
 documents = db.tbl_TrnTicketDocument.Get(x => x.FK_TicketId == TicketId && x.IsActive == true).Select(s => new DocumentTypeModel()
        {
            DocumentTypeNameEnglish = s.tbl_MstDocumentType.DocumentTypeNameEnglish
        }).ToList().Distinct(new DocumentTypeModelComparer()).ToList();
```

---

Comment: Might try to use DistinctBy (it distinct by given field) but it won`t work on IQueryable (it present in MoreLinq - can be found in NuGet)

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the documenttypemodel and this is the distinct part (so all fields are checked), you probably want the distinct by via https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ, or you can use group by with first see([linq distinct or group by multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582391/linq-distinct-or-group-by-multiple-properties)).
The other option is to select only the DocumentTypeNameEnglish field and you will get the unique documents.

```
 documents = db.tbl_TrnTicketDocument.Get(x => x.FK_TicketId == TicketId && x.IsActive == true).Select(s => new  { documentTypes =s.tbl_MstDocumentType.DocumentTypeNameEnglish}).Distinct().ToList();
```

Hopefully this is what you want, if not can you post more details?

Answer (score -2):

Switch to the below per Vladimir's comment:

```
 .ToList().Distinct();
```

Comment: Note that this has the effect of pulling *all* records from DB into memory and only then filtering out duplicates. If you have a lot of duplicates, this will involve a lot more network UI and object instantition than necessary.

Comment: Please see the checked answer above and let me know how that is any different?

Comment: Nope, buddy!
This will take unwanted memory and could slow down your API!